# Calling abstract method in constructor of abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, abstract

As [CA2214](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-ch/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2214?view=vs-2017) states, one should not call an overridable method in a constructor. However, I've come across a case where I can't see another way to do what I'm trying to achieve and I can't see potential problems arising from breaking this rule:

I have an abstract base class for configurations. In this class, there is logic for how to fetch the values.
My applications have configs that can be made up of certain components. So my SpecificConfig would inherit from ConfigBase and be made up of ConfigComponentA and ConfigComponentB:

```
public abstract class ConfigBase
{
    protected ConfigBase()
    {
        this.InitializeMembers();
        this.SetConfigValues();
    }

    protected abstract void InitializeMembers();

    private void SetConfigValues() {
        // Set the config values
        // Depends on members initialized in InitializeMembers
    }
}

public class ConfigComponentA
{
    public string FieldA1;
    public string FieldA2;
}

public class ConfigComponentB
{
    public string FieldB1;
    public string FieldB2;
}

public sealed class SpecificConfig : ConfigBase
    public SpecificConfig() : base() {}

    public ConfigComponentA ConfigA;
    public ConfigComponentB ConfigB;

    protected override void InitializeMembers()
    {
        this.ConfigA = new ConfigComponentA();
        this.ConfigB = new ConfigComponentB();
    }
}
```

The main point is that the configs could be made up of different components, and I want to avoid code duplication by having the logic for fetching and setting the config values in SetConfigValues() in the base class.

I have a feeling there may be a better way of going about this altogether, but I don't really see any unexpected behaviour that could come of this. Is there a better approach?

Comment: If that's common config initialization .. then I don't see any reason why can't you do what you have currently

Comment: You can make SetConfigValues() protected and let child classes call it themselves after they init configs (which in this case they do in constructor, while InitializeMembers() is removed. Or just disable this warning if you think problems that can arise are not applicable in your case.

Comment: You might also consider a factory method doing the construction and initialization of the object in two steps.

Comment: Why is this class hierarchy needed?  Does `ConfigBase` provide some shared behavior for sub-classes?